# Quarterly Date Series becomes NaT when included in Column

Tags: python, datetime

I create the "Date" Series:

```
Date = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2005-06-30', 
                       periods = 63, freq = '3M'))
```

Which works correctly:

```
Date.head()
```

OUTPUT

```
0   2005-06-30
1   2005-09-30
2   2005-12-31
3   2006-03-31
4   2006-06-30
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then, when I try to add it to my df, I only get NaT value:

```
Median_Property_Prices['Date'] = Date
Median_Property_Prices.head()
```

OUTPUT

```
Period    | Central_&_Greater_London_Median_Property_Price | Date
----------|------------------------------------------------|-------
2005 - Q2 | 275034.852                                     | NaT
2005 - Q3 | 281568.432                                     | NaT
2005 - Q4 | 293130.952                                     | NaT
2006 - Q1 | 299590.252                                     | NaT
2006 - Q2 | 299385.228                                     | NaT
```

What am I missing? Why do I not have the quarterly data in the Date column?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your sample data and I have been able to create the `Date` column. See if you can run the code below and add the `Date` field to the dataframe.

```
# create quarterly series
Date = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2005-06-30', periods = 63, freq = '3M'))
# create dataframe
Median_Property_Prices = pd.DataFrame({
    'Period': ['2005 - Q2', '2005 - Q3', '2005 - Q4', '2006 - Q1', '2006 - Q2'],
    'Central_&_Greater_London_Median_Property_Price': [275034.852, 281568.432, 293130.952, 299590.252, 299385.228]
})
# add date field
Median_Property_Prices['Date'] = Date
```

When I call `Median_Property_Prices` this is the output.

```
       Period | Central_&_Greater_London_Median_Property_Price  | Date
--------------|-------------------------------------------------|------------
0   2005 - Q2 | 275034.852                                      | 2005-06-30
1   2005 - Q3 | 281568.432                                      | 2005-09-30
2   2005 - Q4 | 293130.952                                      | 2005-12-31
3   2006 - Q1 | 299590.252                                      | 2006-03-31
4   2006 - Q2 | 299385.228                                      | 2006-06-30
```

If you can generate the output above with the code above, there may be an issue with the original dataframe you have.